# Seeing image dimensions in silx viewer Plot2D

Tags: python, qt

I am using a custom silx viewer to visualize a series of hdf5 imagens stored in a single file. The default silx viewer Plot2D behaviour lets you browse trough images with a slider:

[image]

I want to apply a custom PlotAction that modifies the image. It works with (complete code at the end of question):

```
class SumAction(PlotAction):
    def __init__(self, plot, parent=None):
    
    sum_icon = qt.QIcon("./matrix.png")
    
    super(SumAction, self).__init__(
        plot, icon=sum_icon, text='Sum',
        tooltip='Sum 100 to each image pixel.',
        triggered=self.__sum,
        checkable=True, parent=parent)

def __sum(self, checked):

    activeImage = self.plot.getActiveImage()

    if activeImage is None:
        qt.QMessageBox.information(
            self.plot,
            "Plot data is None. Open a valid 2D image to use this function."
        )
        
    data = activeImage.getData()
        
    self.originalData = activeImage.getData()
    data+=100
    activeImage.setData(data)
```

The thing is: whenever i slide right or left, the modification is gone. Having as premise that the best way to make this persistent is to override the slider function to call my custom action if my action button is checked (I could be wrong), i want to do something like:

```
def slideToImage(image_number):
    super(ActualSlider, self).slideToImage()
    if cool_button == checked:
        do_things_to_image()
```

So that my changes seem persistent. But i couldnt find anything about how to override the slider function. Is there a way to do that?

Complete code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import numpy

from silx.gui import qt

def createWindow(parent, settings):
    # Local import to avoid early import (like h5py)
    #SOme libraries have to be configured first properly
    from silx.gui.plot.actions import PlotAction
    from silx.gui.widgets.FrameBrowser import FrameBrowser
    from silx.app.view.Viewer import Viewer
    from silx.app.view.ApplicationContext import ApplicationContext
        
    class SumAction(PlotAction):
        def __init__(self, plot, parent=None):
            
            sum_icon = qt.QIcon("./matrix.png")
            
            super(SumAction, self).__init__(
                plot, icon=sum_icon, text='Sum',
                tooltip='Sum 100 to each image pixel.',
                triggered=self.__sum,
                checkable=True, parent=parent)

        def __sum(self, checked):

            activeImage = self.plot.getActiveImage()

            if activeImage is None:
                qt.QMessageBox.information(
                    self.plot,
                    "Plot data is None. Open a valid 2D image to use this function."
                )
                
            data = activeImage.getData()
                
            self.originalData = activeImage.getData()
            data+=100
            activeImage.setData(data)
                            
    class MyApplicationContext(ApplicationContext):
        """This class is shared to all the silx view application."""
    
        def findPrintToolBar(self, plot):
            # FIXME: It would be better to use the Qt API
            return plot._outputToolBar

        def viewWidgetCreated(self, view, widget):
            """Called when the widget of the view was created.

            So we can custom it.
            """
            from silx.gui.plot import Plot2D
            if isinstance(widget, Plot2D):
                toolBar = self.findPrintToolBar(widget)
                action = SumAction(widget, widget)
                toolBar.addAction(action)

    class MyViewer(Viewer):
        def createApplicationContext(self, settings):
            return MyApplicationContext(self, settings)

    window = MyViewer(parent=parent, settings=settings)
    window.setWindowTitle(window.windowTitle() + " [custom]")
    return window


def main(args):
    from silx.app.view import main as silx_view_main
    # Monkey patch the main window creation
    silx_view_main.createWindow = createWindow
    # Use the default launcher
    silx_view_main.main(args)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```